# authorization with python requests and session

Tags: python-3.x, parsing

I'm new in Python. I'm trying to log in to the site, but it doesn’t work out (remain unauthorized). What am I doing wrong?

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'https://kartoteka.ru'
    LOGIN = 'somelogin'
    PWD = 'secretpassword'
    PROMO = ""
    c.get(url)
    loginData = dict(login=LOGIN, pwd=PWD, promo=PROMO)
    c.post(url, data=loginData, headers = {"Referer": "https://kartoteka.ru"})
    page=c.get(url)
    print(page.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first this is it looks like you've missed this input in the login form:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="scratchcard_checkbox" name="scratchcard" value="scratchcard" style="top: 2px; position: relative;margin-right: 4px;">
```

So you should add a `scratchcard` option to your login data.

**Edit**: Here's the whole form:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="auth-ep-select" id="auth-cert-list-area"></div>
    <div class="form-group no-margin-bottom">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 auth-login-label">Промо-код</label>
        <div  class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 auth-text-field">
        <span class="fa fa-lock user-auth-icon"></span>
        <input id="auth_promo" class="form-control  in-auth-control" value="" type="text" name="promo" placeholder="Промо-код"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-12 auth-btn-block text-center" style="margin-top:15px">
        <button type="button" data-loading-text="Войти" class="btn btn-md btn-info auth-btn js-dlg-auth-btn">Войти</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
      <a class="auth-registration-link"  onsubmit="yaCounter23391682.reachGoal('registraciya'); return true;" href="/reguser/" style="color:#ffffff;">Регистрация&nbsp;</a>
      <span>/</span>
      <a class="success auth-buy-ep" href="/uc/" role="button" onsubmit="yaCounter23391682.reachGoal('kypit_ep'); return true;"  title="Купить ЭП">&nbsp;Купить ЭП</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

Why do you bother `GET`ting the url at the start? I don't think that's necessary.

How to you know you remain unauthorised? You're not saving the Request object from when you `POST` with the login data, so how do you know it returns an error code.

BTW, it's much quicker to declare a literal dictionary that create one like that, and you don't need it within the session.

```
import requests

ROOT_URL = 'https://kartoteka.ru'
USERNAME, PASSWORD = 'login', 'pass'
PROMO = ''=

with requests.Session() as c:
    login_data = {'login': USERNAME, 'pwd': PASSWORD, 
                  'promo': PROMO, 'scratchcard': false}
    login_request = c.post(ROOT_URL, 
                           data=login_data, 
                           headers={"Referer": "https://kartoteka.ru"})
    login_request.raise_for_status()
    print(c.get(ROOT_URL).content)
```

I don't know if that will fix anything, but it's probably a start.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But your code doesn't work either. I check the result by analyzing html.
I guess the problem is that the first step is clicking on the "Sign in" button.
<button type = "button" class = "sign-in btn btn-md btn-info" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "# AuthModal" title = "Login"> <i class = "fa fa- sign-in "> </i> <span class =" hidden-xs hidden-sm "> Login </span> </button>

Comment: But I have no idea how to click on it

Comment: That's not the issue, because there is no form around the the button to toggle that modal, so it's all in JS. Perhaps the `scratchcard` should be set to `scratchcard`.

Comment: Maybe try logging in with another tool (like Postman or curl) first to get everything working, and see what happens when you login, then try in Python. If you open the console and then login manually, you should be able to track the requests that the browser sends, and then see exactly what happens. I would expect a session cookie to be set by the site. Sorry I can't be more help.